# Cross Dependent Cascading Dropdowns in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

My concept is this: There are three columns relating to a definite hierarchy. I would like our users to be able to input into the combo boxes in whichever order they'd like and have the information pulled in the other two combo boxes be reactive to this.

Example: `Country / State / (County/Region/District/City)` in a tracker; The sql referenced table with source info would be `Country_Name, State_Name, County_Name`

If one were to put in "Vienna" into County, one would have options for Georgia, Missiouri, etc. under state, and United States and Austria as options for Country (I have no idea the larger provincial structure for Austria to add them to a state field--this is meant as an analogous example).

If one were to put in "Virginia" under state one would get United States as an option for Country, and Various counties as options for County.

The hierarchy would be relatively normal for inputting a country, as that's the natural drill down.

I do understand how to do a cascading (one-way) combo-box. The problem lies with being unable to use a nested Iif in the control source, or being unable to temporarily amend the control source through `_AfterUpdate` cases--please excuse the pseudocode:

```
Private Sub State_AfterUpdate()
    If Country = "" And County = "" Then
        Me.Country.ControlSource = "SELECT Country_Name FROM Natl_Structure WHERE State_Name = " & Forms![Postal]![State]

        Me.County.ControlSource = "Select County_Name FROM Natl_Structure WHERE State_Name = " & Forms![Postal]![State] & ";"

    Elseif Country <> "" And County = "" Then
        Me.County ControlSource = "Select County_Name FROM Natl_Structure WHERE (State_Name = " & Forms![Postal]![State]) AND (Country_Name = " & Forms![Postal]![Country] & ";"
```

...and flip it for the opposite case. And set up the opposite of the first case for if both were setup (not that it would be necessary at that point, but just to account for all cases). Then apply the same sort of measure to the other two combo boxes.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use IIF in your control sources to check if there is already a value in the other combo boxes or not.

```
Me.County.ControlSource = "Select County_Name FROM Natl_Structure WHERE 1=1" & 
IIf(IsNull(Forms![Postal]![State]),"", " AND State_Name = " & Forms![Postal]![State]) & 
IIf(IsNull(Forms![Postal]![Country]),""," AND Country = " & Forms![Postal]![Country])
```